# How can I get return value of stored procedure when using SqlDataReader?

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql, sqldatareader

Is it not possible to get the return value of a stored procedeure when using a datareader? The return value is always null, but the SP returns a valid int from within SSMS.

```
myCommand.CommandText = "GetVenueVideos";
SqlParameter retVal = new SqlParameter("@returnValue",SqlDbType.Int);
retVal.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
myCommand.Parameters.Add(retVal);
myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
if (myReader.Read() && myReader.HasRows)
{
    int returnValue = Convert.ToInt32(retVal.Value);
    //returnValue is null at this point
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Agh. I've found out the reader has to be closed to get the return value! So inside the if {} block above, I added:

```
myReader.Close(); // Need to close data reader before getting return value.
int returnValue = (int)myCommand.Parameters["@returnValue"].Value;
```

...and now it works OK!

Comment: This is actually documented on MSDN, although not very prominently. For example, see the *"Remarks"* section of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx or the *"Closing the DataReader"* section of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz.aspx.

Comment: Very nice! Closing the DataReader did the trick for me as well.