# C# capture return value from stored proc when using ExecuteReader

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I'm trying to capture the return value from a stored proc, it should return 1, but the below C# code always shows 0 instead.

I do know that you should only read values of output paramers and the return value AFTER the datareader has been closed, but I am doing that and it still is using the wrong value.

```
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                con.Open();

                con.InfoMessage += (object obj, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e) => {
                    spPrintOutput2.Add(e.Message);
                };

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 60 * 60;   // 1 hour timeout
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@returnValue", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Direction
                    = System.Data.ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

                using (SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    do
                    {
                        while (dataReader.Read())
                            spPrintOutput2.Add(dataReader[0].ToString());
                    } while (dataReader.NextResult());
                }

                spReturnValue = (int)cmd.Parameters["@returnValue"].Value;  // *** Should be 1 but it is 0

                cmd.Dispose();
            }
```

Comment: As an FYI, the `RETURN` value is meant to display the success status of an SP, not return data. `0` means that the SP was successful, and anything else (`1` in your case) means **failure** and represents the failure reason. If you have `RETURN 1` this infers that your SP always fails.

Comment: I am using the return value for that reason, when it returns 1 I am signalling that a problem happened, it wasn't successful
The RETURN 1 is within an IF block so it doesnt always return 1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get return value of stored procedure when using SqlDataReader?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8093317/2029983)

Comment: @Larnu - no because they are saying you need to close the datareader before getting the value from the parameter, but I am already doing that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to specify `CommandType.StoredProcedure`. By default the command type is `CommandType.Text`, which does not expect a return value.

Try adding:

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Comment: Thanks Dan, this was the problem yes. I was just executing the stored procedure using CommandType Text like "exec dbo.bb_output_staging @ViewName='WebCount_ID40_WCOutputID5_20200213_094941_Test',...."